# Soalrium PHP Extract query setFile()

Tags: php, solarium, solr-cell

I am using Solarium library for Solr and I am getting files from database in blob format and I want to send them to solr cell using [extract query](https://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/queries/extract-query/).

However, the setFile() method in the Extract Query expects a local file path as input, but I want to avoid saving the binary file to the local storage before sending it to Solr instead I want to pass a binary file directly. Is it possible somehow to send a binary file directly with extract query or is there some better approach to this?

Comment: Depending how the setFile is implemented, you might be able to use a stream wrapper like 'php://memory' but that's just a guess.